# 0403-057 Syntax error at line 43 : `<' is not matched

Tags: unix, aix, isql

I am receiving below error

> 0403-057 Syntax error at line 43 : `<' is not matched.

for below isql connection object on AIX server.

```
isql -Uusername -Sserver -Ppassword -w 5000  -s"|" << EOF >>$LOG
```

I have looked for various spacing options but all the same.

The value of $LOG is below.

```
LOG="./log.txt"
```

which is of course declared before the isql connection statement.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried removing the space between the `<<` and the `EOF`? What's your shell (`echo $0` will tell you)?

Comment: yes I did. all the same. my shell is bash

Comment: Are you putting `EOF` on its own line, unindented, at the end of your input?

Comment: This message was sent by `ksh` not by `bash`. You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @mwp I didn't get you.

Comment: Bash errors don't normally start with a code number, I'd guess that's actually an isql error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess i figured out the answer here.
I had to strip my script completely for that though

```
while read line
do

echo "$line" | while IFS=\| read row_id col_name col_value
do

isql -Uusername -Sserver -Ppassword -w 5000  -s"|" << EOF >> $LOG

EOF

done < $FILE
```

I removed all the sql statements from the above while loop to make it a bit less messy and easier to find out the culprit. Found out that I missed closing one of the while loops.

Below is the correct loop.

```
while read line
do
echo "$line" | while IFS=\| read tranche_id col_name col_value
do

isql -Uusername -Sserver -Ppassword -w 5000  -s"|" << EOF >> $LOG

EOF

done

done < $FILE
```

Sad how a 'done' missed my mind.

Comment: Instead of spaces use quotes: `cmd ... <<"EOF" >>"$LOG"`

Answer (score 0):

if you have bellow errors;

```
^M:  not found.
0403-057 Syntax error at line x : `if' is not matched.
```

create .gitattributes file and insert bellow shell script. save and add .gitattributes file to your project.

```
*.sh text eol=lf
```

This .gitattributes file configure .sh file to run in unix